# Compile fcgi gem on ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: ruby, fastcgi

- OS: Ubuntu 14.04 LTS
- Ruby Version: 2.3.1p112
- `gem -v` --> 2.5.1
- `a2enmod fastcgi` --> `Module fastcgi already enabled`

I tried running `gem install fcgi` but it fails with this error

```
have_header: checking for fastcgi/fcgiapp.h... -------------------- no

"gcc -E -I/usr/local/include/ruby-2.3.0/x86_64-linux -I/usr/local/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/backward -I/usr/local/include/ruby-2.3.0 -I.     -O3 -fno-fast-math -ggdb3 -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-pare$conftest.c:3:29: fatal error: fastcgi/fcgiapp.h: No such file or directory
 #include <fastcgi/fcgiapp.h>
                             ^
compilation terminated.
checked program was:
/* begin */
1: #include "ruby.h"
2:
3: #include <fastcgi/fcgiapp.h>
/* end */
```

Is there a dependency I am missing? the [Github](https://github.com/alphallc/ruby-fcgi-ng) page for the gem is not helpful at all since the link to the "CGI DEV KIT" is broken.

Answer (score 0):

Libraries required to compile the gem successfully:

`sudo apt-get install libfcgi libfcgi-dev`